# Issue with filtering on dates

Tags: rally

I need some help with rally.

I'm currently looking at creating a simple app to generate a report, on the number of stories that are added to a particular project each week. I'm simply using the SOAP connection, and I have it all working. I'm able to load stories when filtering onanything, except dates.

maybe someone can help me see what I'm doing wrong.

I am simply using the filter:

```
((CreationDate >= 01-01-12) and (CreationDate <= 07-01-12))
```

I get the same results from my filtering as using a custom grid filter through the site. I have been trying to get this working for the last few hours, and I think it should be something very simple.

As a test run, I have also been trying different options in the custom grid. I should also point out that this is a project with lots of stories, with creation dates going back 18 months, till today: here is what I have tried:

```
(CreationDate >= 01-01-12) No Results
(CreationDate <= 01-01-12) All results (unfiltered)

//Every format i can think of for the dates... dd-MM-yy is the only one that seems to work

(CreationDate >= "01-01-12") No Results
(CreationDate <= "01-01-12") All results (unfiltered)
(CreationDate > "01-01-12") No Results
(CreationDate < "01-01-12") All results (unfiltered)
(CreationDate = "01-01-12") No Results
(CreationDate = "01-01-12") No results
```

Any idea's? is CreationDate incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin,

All of the dates in Rally's WSAPI are in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. At least, I think you will need a 4-digit year. You can also look at the format of the response in our [interactive WSAPI documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/).

- Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response. Unfortunatley, i have been using the WSAPI page, and although i have found it useful for finding the fields that i am able to query, i have been getting the same responces as through the website for the queries.  Also with the 4 digit year, i get an error when putting 4 digits in e.g. putting in 01-01-2012 returns Unexpected character at 12.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get notified of your comment.